# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "33"

Tags: java

```
class liste
{
    int numara;
    String ad;
    String soyad;
    liste sonraki;
} 

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\bagli.txt"));
    BufferedReader reader = null;  
    String s;
    Scanner klavye = new Scanner(System.in);
    listeler mylist = new listeler();
    while(br.ready())
    {   
        s=br.readLine();

        String[] firstLine = s.split("#");
        liste kayıt = new liste();
        kayıt.numara = Integer.parseInt(firstLine[0].trim());
        kayıt.ad =  firstLine[1].trim();
        kayıt.soyad =  firstLine[2].trim();
        mylist.ekle(kayıt);
    }
```

I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "33"
```

on the following line:

```
kayıt.numara = Integer.parseInt(firstLine[0].trim());
```

I don't understand why I get this error.

Comment: Please show the actual exception stack trace, not a paraphrasing of it. Please show the data file as well, or the key parts of it.

Comment: If the two consecutive double-quotes in the error message are correct, then `firstLine[0].trim()` has a trailing double-quote character that must be eliminated before parsing the integer.

Answer (score 0):

[NumberFormatException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html) error from the parseInt function when the string is in the wrong format. The easiest way to troubleshoot this is to output the exact string you are trying to parse.  This is typically done with a [system.out.println](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#out)(*insertStringVariableHere*).

In my experience the error almost always comes from an additional space for quote or some other unexpected character surrounding the number.

Comment: What should be the correct code ? bagli.txt in

33#ahmet#korkusuz

44#hanife#demir

66#murat#tok